# error in implementing seconds countdown using state in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component where I am trying to start a countdown from 30 to 0 as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

function Countdown () {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState('');
  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(false);

  const startTimer = () => {
    setStart(true)
    setTime('30')
  }

  const startTiming = setInterval(() => {
    if (start) {
      if (time !== '0') {
        setTime((parseInt(time) - 1).toString());
      } else {
        clearInterval(startTiming)
        setStart(false);
      }
    }
  }, 1000)
  return (<>
    { start ? time : 'wait to start' }
    <button onClick={startTimer}>Start Timer</button>
  </>)
}

export default Countdown;
```

I want to start the countdown from 30 seconds by clicking the button. However, once the countdown gets to about 23 seconds, it no longer counts down consistently by 1 second and instead seems to go into an infinite loop - would anyone know why this is? Ideally I'd like to implement this by using the start state.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a `useTimer(hz)` hook that captures an `offset` when the user clicks <kbd>Start</kbd>. This way `elapsed` time is always correct and doesn't drift due to imperfect timeout deltas. The hook returns `[elapsed, { start, stop }]` which is the total elapsed time with floating point precision and `start` and `stop` controls. The optional `hz` parameter controls the frequency at which the timer updates.

The `Countdown` component has `seconds` as well as a configurable `hz` property. By subtracting `elapsed` time from `seconds`, we know how much time is remaining.

<kbd>Run</kbd> the program below and click <kbd>Start</kbd> on each timer and don't forget to have a good time!

```js
function useTimer(hz = 100) {
  const [[offset, now], setState] = React.useState([null, null])
  const start = React.useCallback(_ => setState([Date.now(), Date.now()]))
  const stop = React.useCallback(_ => setState([null, null]))
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    if (offset == null) return
    const t = setTimeout(_ => { setState([offset, Date.now()]) }, 1000 / hz)
    return _ => clearTimeout(t)
  }, [offset, now])
  return [offset == null ? 0 : (now - offset) / 1000, {start, stop}]
}
    
function Countdown({ seconds, hz = 1 }) {
  const [elapsed, { start, stop }] = useTimer(hz)
  React.useEffect(_ => { if (elapsed > seconds) stop() }, [elapsed, stop])
  return <div>
    <pre>{`<Countdown seconds={${seconds}} hz={${hz}} />`}</pre>
    { elapsed > seconds
      ? 0
      : (seconds - elapsed).toFixed(2)
    }
    { elapsed > 0
      ? <button type="button" onClick={stop} children="Reset" />
      : <button type="button" onClick={start} children="Start" />
    }
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render([
  <Countdown seconds={30} />,
  <Countdown seconds={20} hz={10} />,
  <Countdown seconds={10} hz={100} />
], document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
pre { background-color: #ffe; padding: 0.25rem 0; margin: 0; }
p { margin: 0; }
div { margin: 0 0 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```